# What happened immediately after Rey leaves Ahch-To?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, rey

In The Last Jedi, after Rey leaves Ahch-To she

> jettisons from the Millennium Falcon in an escape pod

did she ever show any surprise that

> she was headed into a bombardment of Leia's ship

?

And when she

> left Chewie did she expect to get captured by the First Order?

That part just made me really confused, like I completely missed the part where she learned about all the stuff that

> Finn apparently was trying to protect her from

in the beginning of the movie.

Comment: Nothing has really come as a surprise in the Star Wars universe since that time when Vader said he was Luke's father.

Comment: After Rey interacted with Kylo Ren through the Force network, she started believing that there was still good in him and she was going to save him from the dark side despite being warned by Luke.

Comment: @Bat, but how did she wind up where she did, luck?  At least when Luke went to confront Vader he told someone he was going to do it.

Comment: The answer is Force Vision..

Comment: It seemed like her pod piloted straight to the doorway, seemed like it was intentional.

Comment: @PeterTurner If I may quote a famous Jedi master, there is no such thing as luck in this galaxy far, far away.

Comment: @edl I guess I figured it was intentional, it was just blurry, I guess. It made it seem like that homing beacon part was an utterly unimportant fascile of the movie - it would have been funnier if she and chewie would have flown to casino royale planet to save Finn and Rose.  They must have re-wrote that part a few times, something is definitely untoward in those 5 minutes of the movie.

Comment: Maybe she intended to rejoin the rebels, but landed there and the tractor beam took her away, or she had communicated with the rebels. Plenty could've happened off-screen

Comment: @edl I thought she had a "oh crap" sort of look on her face when she landed where she did, but I can't remember any dialogue at that point (from her at least)

Comment: She did, I don't know what they planned, whatever it was it all happened off-screen.

Comment: @Edlothiad I figured it was a combination of destination targeting and tractor beaming by the First Order ship. There weren't any fighters or bombers for Flight Controllers to worry about, so when a small craft with a lifeform on board comes barreling in they probably spilled their coffee on themselves trying to activate a tractor beam to control its approach.

Answer (score 4):

She *intended* to be captured by the First Order.

She doesn't specifically know about the bombardment, and given her limited view from the escape pod she probably doesn't see it, but she knows that the Resistance might be in trouble: when she and Chewbacca try to contact them from the Falcon, they fail. Hence her instructions to Chewie to get in and out as quickly as possible, no heroics. (Very approximate paraphrase there; haven't seen the movie enough times to quote it.)

Comment: Will provide a quote when I get some time :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure she ever notices the bombardment. She really doesn't have a moment's rest after jettisoning into the middle of an active battlefield (I know I'd be more concerned with not getting shot or hitting debris).

As to her capture

> Kylo Ren was expecting her, due to the Force-link. Note how she was guided into the bay, where she was met by Ren and a stormtrooper bearing handcuffs. I think she was surprised at the handcuffs, but I read her face as more of "I just walked into the lair of the enemy". It's takes some fortitude to confront someone like that on their turf, even if you've had a Force-vision indicating Ren will turn in some fashion.

Comment: This is also a callback to *Return of the Jedi*, where Luke voluntarily surrendered to Darth Vader in hopes of turning him.